Why is my Google Earth Engine JavaScript taking so long to execute?
My script is quite basic, and it is still taking GEE about 3-5 mins to run it. How can I make it faster?


// Set geometry of concern 
var pointJSP = ee.Geometry.Point([86.465263, 20.168076]);

// Center the map at that point.
Map.centerObject(pointJSP, 14);


// Set dates 
//Sentinel
// Time Block 1
var startDate1 = '2024-02-01';
var endDate1 = '2024-03-01';


// Landsat 8 
// Time Block 2
var startDate2 = '2024-02-01';
var endDate2 = '2024-03-01';



// Function for calculating and adding indices - NDVI, NDWI, and NDSI - to the image collections
var addIndices = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['NIR', 'RED']).rename('NDVI');
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['NIR', 'SWIR1']).rename('NDWI');
  var ndsi = image.normalizedDifference(['SWIR1', 'SWIR2']).rename('NDSI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi).addBands(ndsi);
};


// Add permanent water mask
// JRC - Occurrence
var Water = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_4/GlobalSurfaceWater').select('occurrence');
var visualization = {
  bands: ['occurrence'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['ffffff', 'ffbbbb', '0000ff']
};

Map.addLayer(Water, visualization, 'Water Occurrence', false);

// Implement a threshold.
var permWater = Water.gt(80).unmask();

// Map the threshold.
Map.addLayer(permWater,
    {
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        palette: ['white', 'blue']
    },
    'Water vs Non-water', false);



// Visualisation Parameters 
var visTRUE = {
    bands: ['RED_p30', 'GREEN_p30', 'BLUE_p30'],
    min: 8500,
    max: 14000, 
    gamma: 1.3
}; 

var visTRUE_sent = {
  bands: ["RED_p30", "GREEN_p30", "BLUE_p30"], 
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.2, 
  gamma: 1.3
}


// Define classification image visualization parameters.
var classificationVis = {
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    palette: ['785a5a', 'ffc1b0','d63000' ] // Class 0 = others, class 1 = dry_ponds, class 2 = aquaculture
};




// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Step 1.2 - Get relevant ImageCollections from Sentinel and Landsat8
// Mask and filter by location, date and cloud-free composite (ref. F4.3), calculate indices, add and rename bands

// 2.1 Sentinel 

var sentinel = sentinelBase.select
    (
        ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12'],
        ['BLUE', 'GREEN', 'RED', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2']
    );

var sentinelIndices = sentinel.map(addIndices);

// Composite for Time Block 1
var sentinelImageCol_1 = ee.ImageCollection(sentinelIndices)
    .filterBounds(SamplingArea)
    .filterDate(startDate1, endDate1)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 50));
    
print('Composite for Sentinel', sentinelImageCol_1);

var composite1 = sentinelImageCol_1.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([30])).clip(SamplingArea).mask(permWater.eq(0));
Map.addLayer(composite1, visTRUE_sent , 'Composite 1 Sentinel', false);


// 2.2 Landsat 8 
var landsat8 = landsat8base.select
    (
        ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7'],
        ['BLUE', 'GREEN', 'RED', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2']
    );

var landsat8Indices = landsat8.map(addIndices);

// Composite for Time Block 2
var l8ImageCol_2 = ee.ImageCollection(landsat8Indices)
    .filterBounds(SamplingArea)
    .filterDate(startDate2, endDate2)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER', 50));
    
print('Composite for Landsat 8', l8ImageCol_2);

var composite2 = l8ImageCol_2.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([30])).clip(SamplingArea).mask(permWater.eq(0));
Map.addLayer(composite2, visTRUE , 'Composite 2 Landsat', false);


I could make the date variables the same, but I would like to have the flexibility to have different date ranges for both Landsat and Sentinal. Other than that, I'm not sure how to make this script more efficient.

As with all optimization, start by working out where the bottlenecks are. Add some calls to Date.now(), (or better, performance.now() if it's supported) throughout the code and log the results. This should give you a feel for where to focus your efforts.
